# Insert position in database with google map in Angular2

Tags: google-maps, angular

I'm trying to build an Angula2 application,I want to get the position(longitude and latitude) when i click on a point in the map to be able to insert those fields in my database.
Here is the Map code:

```
<sebm-google-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom" [backgroundColor]="backgroundColor" >
  <sebm-google-map-marker *ngFor=" let post of posts" [latitude]="post.lapti" [longitude]="post.longi" ></sebm-google-map-marker>
</sebm-google-map>
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the mapclick event :

```
<sebm-google-map (mapClick)="getPosition($event)" [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom" [backgroundColor]="backgroundColor" >
  <sebm-google-map-marker *ngFor=" let post of posts" [latitude]="post.lapti" [longitude]="post.longi" ></sebm-google-map-marker>
</sebm-google-map>
```

...

```
getPosition(event: MouseEvent ) {
  let coords: LatLngLiteral = event.coords; //coords.lat, coords.lng are numbers
  console.log(coords.lat); //the clicked point latitude
  console.log(coords.lng); //the clicked point longitude
    ...
}
```

Plunker here : http://plnkr.co/edit/UWl3Tm

Comment: Can you explain more what i should write in the getPosition function?

Comment: I add `console.log`, is it better or am I missing the sens of your question ?

Comment: it says that property coords does not exist on type MouseEvent

Comment: Is your MouseEvent imported from here : https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/blob/66806e57e0e7755c4314e16009fc898aaedde685/src/core/map-types.ts ?

Comment: No,I should add those 2 lines in app-module,or install it with npm?

Comment: I added a Plunker for you

Comment: Thank you,i used event:any instead of event:MouseEvent and it worked

Comment: Why not ? There is an open issue now, for missing types here : https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/issues/982